# In PHP header('Location: /facemash'); is not refreshing the Page?

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am creating a **facebook facemash** like application, http://www.fancykart.com/facemash 
it is working fine in localhost WAMP but it is not working fine while i put it on my web host. I have to refresh the page to reload new content and update latest score. Can you suggest what is the problem might be.

I have index.php and rate.php for page.

in rate.php

```
header('Location: /facemash');
```

this was my header.

Comment: Check PHP error_log maby there are some errors displayed before `header()`? `header()` won't wor after something is returned to browser.

Comment: where to check these errors? my hosting uses cpanel

Answer (score 0):

You're probably reloading from a cache. Try this before changing your location: `header("Cache-Control: no-cache");`

Answer (score 0):

Is that the first line of code being executed or is there other code first.  I usually use double quoatations when doing a header call, also for the location of facemash you should probably append the http path and concatenate facemash to it, also try adding the extension of facemash just to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the complete url

```
http://www...
```